# Ruby on Rails - How to show foreign key values in one model to another

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'am new to Ruby on Rail 4.

I have two models `Newspaper` and `Language`

```
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :newspapers
end

class Newspaper < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :language
end
```

This is the tables of two models

```
language
--------

* id
* name

newspaper
---------

* id
* name
* language_id
```

After generate `controllers` and `db migration`, Newspaper `index` page populate all records with `language_id(means reference id)` as a table format. But I need to display `newspaper` corresponding `language` name in the table.

How to achieve this one? Also is there any problem in making a relationship with these models.

Comment: What's in your `index` view?

Comment: @MarekLipka : In Controller, index defined with `@newspapers = Newspapers.all`. On view page, this `@newspapers` instance object, iteratively displayed in a table.

Comment: Did you try suggestions from my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
newspaper.language_id
```

you just need to use:

```
newspaper.language.name
```

or, if you aren't sure that every `Newspaper` belongs to corresponding `Language`, you could use [`try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) method:

```
newspaper.language.try(:name)
```

And BTW, to avoid N+1 queries problem, you should include your `language` association while fetching `newspapers` in controller, with `includes` method:

```
@newspapers = Newspaper.includes(:language).your_other_scopes
```

This way, you need to generate two `SQL` queries to fetch both `newspapers` and each one's associated `language`. If you didn't use `includes`, there would be a `SQL` query generated to fetch each newspaper's language, which would be much less efficient. More info here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: I'm not giving downvote :-(. And your second method which is using `try` method working fine. But I have 2 more doubts in that. Initially `@newspaper` instance object holds each newspaper of `language` details too. And second one, could you elaborate more that last method using `includes`

Comment: @Ranjith edited my answer for explanation of `includes`. But I don't understand your first doubt. Could you explain it?

Comment: According to your first scenario, on index page if I defined like this `newspaper.language.name`, getting `No method error`.

Comment: @Ranjith it seems not all your `newspapers` has corresponding `language` record. I didn't know this, but I was assuming it had been possible and that's why I wrote 'second scenario'.

Comment: It has language. But this one working fine in `show` page. Anyway thanks for your response.

Comment: @Ranjith it's a little bit strange then. Please go to `rails console` and check the `Newspaper` record with `id` equal to result of `Newspaper.all.detect { |n| !n.language }`. This way you can debug this behavior.